# Is the 'SELECT IN' pyramid good practice?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying understand the best pattern or practices to write SQL queries which involve multiple tables, such as permissions on objects. I can get the result I'm looking for but want to know if this is best practice.

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM windows WHERE id IN(
    SELECT `window` FROM window_groups WHERE `group` IN(
         SELECT DISTINCT `group` FROM user_groups WHERE `user` = 1
    )
)
```

**Question:** Is this `SELECT IN()` "Pyramid" good practice?

Comment: Basically nothing bad. But "is it  a good practice" closely depends on how huge is the data to work upon.

Comment: @cFreed ok cool, should I consider using a `view` if it were large dataset?

Comment: I think JOINs would make the code more maintainable if you ever need to add additional matching columns, which isn't something you can do with WHERE IN.

Comment: @JordanDavis a view won't grant you performance improvements. A materialized view might.

Comment: You can always change at least one level of that into a regular join if it feels better

Comment: In fact, a view is nothing else than a "hidden query", which is executed anyway. So it's the same.

Comment: Okay cool thanks guys, that clarifies a lot for me!

Comment: I once had a coworker argue that using `in` was a sign of a developer who didn't understand joins. Personally I think he was completely clueless. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with this construction.

Comment: @shawnt00 ok cool, good to know.

Comment: On the other hand I've heard that it doesn't always optimize well on MySql so you do have that practical consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend this pattern for one reason -
It enables you to retrieve information only from the outer table, which make it unqualified for many use-cases as well as hard to debug.

Comment: Ok so for these reasons, would you use a `join`?

Comment: @JordanDavis - yes.